# Android: Create a Quick Action Menu

Tags: android, menu, quickaction

I need to create some type of quick action menu that appears to the right side of the clicked item (button) whenever the user clicks the button.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

When the user clicks button1 I want the "sub quick action menu" to appear like it's shown in the image above.
Is there anyway to do this 'natively' in android?

I have found this plugin but it only allows you to show the menu from the top or bottom of the button.
https://github.com/lorensiuswlt/NewQuickAction3D

Answer (score 5):

As tyczj said, you could achieve that with a PopupMenu. The idea is that the popup menu will inflate a custom view with all the elements, having as background a 9 patch image.
[Here's a blog post](http://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/05/06/how-to-create-popups-in-android/) that shows how to do that. Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 4):

You can do the same using Quick Action Menu, for more details you can follow the

"http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/521455/Quick-action-pattern-in-Android-and-simple-impleme" 
    Link.

In example Items are presented in horizontal manner, whereas you can manage them, like listview as per your requirement.

Answer (score 2):

there is a [PopupMenu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html) but there is no arrow or anything pointing to where it came from. Its basically the same thing that comes up when clicking the Overflow actionbar item

Comment: Do you know if there are any other options besides the PopupMenu?

Comment: not besides that 3rd party library that you found. You are trying to replicate an iOS element that android does not have.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this link can help you ;) But instead of sliding use press button.

[Making a slide menu](http://v4all123.blogspot.nl/2013/11/simple-sliding-menu-example-in-android.html)