# customize dialog box containing images in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-canvas

I want to implement a dialog having multiple images, which will be shown on clicking an image.

What's this thing shown in red bounded area in this image?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that is quick action bar see here

[Android: Create a Quick Action Menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17370532/android-create-a-quick-action-menu)

and

http://www.xoriant.com/blog/android/android-ui-design-pattern-quick-action-bar.html

Comment: Ok Thanx that can be helpful :)