# How to open alertdialog with animation up to bottom by onclick list Item?

Tags: android, android-listview

I want to open a dialog that animates from top to bottom by onlick android list item.

Comment: Maybe [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#PopupMenu) might be useful.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9467026/change-dialog-position-on-the-screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can this [Quick action pattern in Android and simple implemention.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/521455/Quick-action-pattern-in-Android-and-simple-impleme) . I expect you will get your solution, hopefully.Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a `PopupMenu` and set an anchor view of the list item . The popup will appear below the anchor if there is room, or above it if there is not.

```
 PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(this, itemView);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

[Android: Create a Quick Action Menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17370532/android-create-a-quick-action-menu)

The view which can be the anchor will be the view you obtain in the OnItemSelectedListener